# Spring batch with JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: spring-batch, query-string

I am using `JdbcCursorItemReader` in Spring batch. I have a `.yaml file which contains external`datasource`details and query. I need to pass dynamic date value from java`BatchReader`class. So my question is using`JdbcCursorItemReader` how to send the query parameter.

My query looks like this:

```
select * from employee where joining date > to_date(?, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I am doing a date conversion here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the date as a job parameter and configure your `JdbcCursorItemReader` with it. You can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/resource/ListPreparedStatementSetterTests-context.xml#L24-L40